# SQL Server 2012 vs SQL Server 2008 Where clause processing

Tags: sql-server-2012, where-clause

We just recently converted to SQL Server 2012 (yes, our company is very behind!) from 2008. In processing some very basic queries, I am finding that the results are different and it appears to be related to the order of the items in the where clause.

For example this query:

```
select 
    source, count(*), sum(book_value) 
from 
    repository.CURRENT_MONTH_14_1
where 
    NET_WAC = 0 or gross_wac = 0 
    and As_Of_Date = '2/29/2016' 
    and Argus_Entity = 'TEST'
group by 
    source
```

The results in SQL Server 2008, would give me only items that satisfy both the `as_of_date` and the `argus_entity` requirement and have a `net_wac` or `gross_wac = 0`.

In SQL Server 2012, I am getting all items that have a `net_wac` or `gross_wac = 0` even if they are in other `argus_entity` or `as_of_dates`.

Is there a certain order required now? Does SQL Server 2012 no longer satisfy all where requirements before giving results?

FYI, I do not have access to the server or any backend information. I'm lucky they allow us to query the information.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `where NET_WAC = 0 or (gross_wac=0 and As_Of_Date='2/29/2016' and Argus_Entity='TEST')` AND > OR. You probably want:`where (NET_WAC = 0 or gross_wac=0) and ( As_Of_Date='2/29/2016' and Argus_Entity='TEST')`

Comment: Whenever you mix `AND` and `OR`, it is best practice to use parentheses to avoid ambiguity.  Additionally, you may run into issues if any of the values of those fields are NULL.  Be sure that any expression correctly handles possible NULL values.

Comment: However the best practice is using parenthesis, as mentioned above, I'm still curious why it behaves different! new version should not break anything that way.

Comment: @FLICKER My guess is that the server or database value for ANSI_NULLS changed.  ["When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, all comparisons against a null value evaluate to UNKNOWN. When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, comparisons of all data against a null value evaluate to TRUE if the data value is NULL."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for info. I'll take a look into this.

Comment: @Bacon Bits Thank you for the information.  We have noticed that using parenthesis fixes the problem as does move the last two conditions to the front of the where clause.  Since we are not involving NULLs in this query (Nulls are different than zeros for our data), would the ANSI_Nulls situation impact this query?

Comment: @flicker  Thanks for confirming the parenthesis fix.  Yes, we were very surprised that we were getting such different results. It is causing a lot more review and update work to ensure our results are accurate.

Comment: "Since we are not involving NULLs in this query [...] would the ANSI_Nulls situation impact this query?" No, if all the fields in the WHERE clause of your query have no NULL values, then ANSI_NULLS should not affect the operation at all.

Comment: "We have noticed that using parenthesis fixes the problem as does move the last two conditions to the front of the where clause."  Your described query is equivalent to `WHERE (As_Of_Date = '2/29/2016' and Argus_Entity = 'TEST' and NET_WAC = 0) or gross_wac = 0`, which is logically different..  Per [order of operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx), AND is before OR.  AND is like multiply and OR is like add.  If you've got `1 + 2 * 3 * 4` (25), and you change it to `3 * 4 * 1 + 2` (14), but what you really want is `(1 + 2) * 3 * 4` (36) then you've got an issue!